# Play Framework renderJSON Issue

Tags: java, json, playframework

I'm new to Play Framework, and having trouble rendering a JSON object.

```
public static void LoginFail() {

 Object[][] statusArray = {

   {"Status", "401"},
   {"Message", "Unauthorized"},
         {"Detail", "No API Key Supplied"}

    };

 renderJSON(statusArray);

}
```

This only displays `[[{},{}],[{},{}],[{},{}]]` ...what am I doing wrong?  I can't find any solid documentation on this.  I tried configuring the route for `Application.LoginFail(format:'json')`, but this did nothing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the looks of your code it seems that your are trying the create a JSON string by yourself, using an array of type Object. My only guess as to why this doesn't work is that GSON (the JSON library in use by play) doesn't know how to convert that to key-value pairs (although your array is 2-dimensional). So how about changing `statusArray` to String and its content to:

```
{
    "Status": "401",
    "Message": "Unauthorized",
    "Detail": "No API Key Supplied"
}
```

Put that into `renderJSON(statusArray)` and you should be fine.

As an alternative you could create a simple `.json` template like the following:

```
{
    "Status": ${status},
    "Message": ${message},
    "Detail": ${detail}
}
```

and call it from a controller method via `render(status, message, detail)`. `status`, `message` and `detail` being Strings here as well. Example controller method:

```
public static void loginFail(final String status, final String message, final String detail) {
    render(status, message, detail);
}
```

and your template would be called `loginFail.json` (the name of the controller method). That way you can call the controller method in whatever logic you have to verify the login. Once the login fails you specify why that is (via status, message and details) by calling the `loginFail` method.

Comment: It's also worth noting that renderJSON can take a String argument as well, which bypasses the GSON parsing.  This is useful if you use something like Jackson for your JSON parsing (as I do).

Answer (score 14):

Do it the simple & reusable way by creating a StatusMessage object

```
public class StatusMessage {
   public String status;
   public String message;
   public String detail;

   public StatusMessage(String status, String message, String detail) [
      this.status = status;
      this.message = message;
      this.detail = detail;
   }
}
```

And then

```
renderJSON(new StatusMessage("401", "Unauthorized", "No API Key Supplied"));
```

Comment: Note, this class should be public. It does not works for me for inner class and class, that was declared inside method

Answer (score 0):

the best in this case is used a HashMap:

```
public static void LoginFail() {
    Map<String, String> status = new HashMap<String, String>();

    status.put("Status", "401");
    status.put("Message", "Unauthorized");
    status.put("Detail", "No API Key Supplied");

    renderJSON(status);
}
```

You can also use another strategy, which is to define an object with the definition of what you want to return and render this:

```
public class Status{

    public String status, message, detail;

    public Status(String status, String message, String detail){
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
        this.detail = detail;
    }
}

public static void LoginFail(){
    Status status = new Status("401", "Unauthorized", "No API Key Supplied");

    renderJSON(status);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do

```
import play.libs.Json;
```

If you are reading JSON from Browser as HTTP Body then

```
 JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();     
 Program program  = Json.fromJson(json, Program.class);
```

Here Program can be your entity class or data transport object.

If you have to fetch records and send it to browser in JSON then do as below

```
  Program program = ProgramDAO.findById(id);
        if(program!=null){
            result = ok(Json.toJson(program));
        }
```

Hope this helps